# Valid images show up broken in transactional emails

Tags: html, email, html-email, sendgrid, transactional-email

So I'm testing out a transactional email using Sendgrid and for some reason the image location is broken even though it exists. I have a really simple image tag, with the FULL path,

```
<img src="https://matter.io/static/img/landing/logo.svg">
```

Yet in the email is shows up as broken. What's strange is when I copy the link sendgrid or gmail creates to the image path

https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/hD3tzoEqBpQwN0NnCaHw6Qsz9nfiDMQH7YONXb0etReSXaeSJtzVFaiiJOSCJR3ch4STfG_ddYH0Oj99MFWNdAUBtw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://matter.io/static/img/landing/logo.svg

It doesn't work, but if I take the link at the end of that huge mess, I can go to it

Is it a problem with serving images through https? Or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gmail proxy that was added to cache images does not support SVG. See [SVG images blocked by gmail proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815613/svg-images-blocked-by-gmail-proxy).

Comment: Thanks sooo much! I would have probably spent another couple of hours trying to figure this out. This is really random