# Is there a trick to display svg images in gmail?

Tags: svg, gmail

I've been trying to display them, but to no avail. I'm wondering if there's a trick to displaying them, because I'm able to get clients such as Outlook to display SVG's. It's really bothering me that gmail can't display them.

Answer (score 101):

Google Gmail does not support SVG at this time. Google Gmail Support said that they will not support it last time i contacted them. Maybe some time in the distant future when SVG becomes more popular and widely used.

Check out this article:

http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2014/01/basics-of-svg-in-email/

And this PDF:

http://stylecampaign.com/blog/blogimages/SVG/QA-SVG-in-email.pdf

Also see this SO question:

[SVG images blocked by gmail proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815613/svg-images-blocked-by-gmail-proxy)

**SVG support in E-Mail Clients**

- iPhone native (iOS 4.3, 5.1, 6.1 and 7.0) **Yes**
- iPhone Mailbox app **No**
- iPhone Gmail app (0.25% of opens as of June 2013) **No**
- iPhone Sparrow app **Yes**
- iPhone Evomail app **Yes**
- iPhone Boxer app **Yes**
- iPhone Yahoo! Mail app **No**
- iPad full-sized native **Yes**
- iPad mini native **Yes**
- iPad Birdseye Mail **Yes**
- iPad Incredimail **Yes**
- iPod Touch native **Yes**
- Android 2.1 Eclair native client **No**
- Android 2.2 Froyo native client **No**
- Android 2.3 Gingerbread native client **No**
- Android 4.0 Ice Creme Sandwich native client **Yes**
- Android 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 Jelly bean native client    **Yes**
- Android Outlook.com app ? txt version
- Android Gmail app **No**
- Android Evomail app **Yes**
- Android Yahoo Mail app  2.0 **No**
- Original Kindle Fire native client **No**
- Kindle Fire HD (New vr. of Silk) native client **Yes**
- Windows Phone 7 **No**
- Windows Phone 7.5 **No**
- Microsoft Surface tablet (Outlook.com/Hotmail) **No**
- Palm webOS 4.5 **No**
- BlackBerry OS 7 **Yes**
- BlackBerry Z10 **Yes**
- DESKTOP (MacMail only client I tested which worked) **Yes**

A list of Desktop and Webmail

- Gmail Firefox: **No support**
- Gmail Chrome: **No support**
- Gmail IE10: **No support**
- Yahoo Mail Firefox: **No support**
- Yahoo Mail Chrome: **No support**
- Yahoo Mail IE10: **No support**
- Outlook.com Firefox: **No support**
- Outlook.com Chrome: **No support**
- Outlook.com IE10: **No support**
- AOL Firefox: **No support**
- AOL Chrome: **No support**
- AOL IE10: **No support**
- Outlook 2007: **No support**
- Outlook 2010: **No support**
- Outlook Express: **No support**
- Outlook 2013: **No support**
- Hotmail Firefox: **No support**
- Apple Mail 5.2 (Mac Book Air): **Support**

**Update 1/2/2020**
You can also look at [this StackOverflow answer on why Google will not support SVG images in Gmail due to the new proxy they implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064771/1203457).

Comment: Do you have a source for this very extensive list?

Comment: The sources are listed as links in my Answer, in PDF, Thanks.

Comment: This answer was last edited on May 23rd. Anything new since?

Comment: Not that I've seen, but you can also check out this link: https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/