# Gmail not displaying image on mail Laravel

Tags: javascript, gmail

I have this problem here when I send an email to Gmail the image is broken while on the other accounts like Outlook or others it shows fine. Only on Gmail it does not show..
the URL looks like this:

```
<img style="font-family:Avenir,Helvetica,sans-serif;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:100%;border:none;width:137px;height:68px" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/jaMu0nmGV-1WVmzYhbjFTDw_r-Qbjx7qGpG0pSuGMkoVPpaQPfScmgx7vrmbYYmI7kH8gS4pC9gmteTfJqPn0FZ2LFRD-A=s0-d-e1-ft#https://evaluo.org/evaluo/assets/evaluollogo.svg" class="CToWUd">
```

As you can see all that proxy blla blla it is integrated before my image link :

```
https://evaluo.org/evaluo/assets/evaluollogo.svg
```

Can someone help with this ..?

Comment: Looks like it's an issue with Gmail displaying .svg files. [Here's a related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33151666/5513864)

Comment: Yea I dont think this is it, I tried also jpeg but same always puts that url with proxy infront

Comment: @Agi The proxy url is normal. What's the `jpeg` url? When I try https://evaluo.org/evaluo/assets/evaluollogo.jpg or https://evaluo.org/evaluo/assets/evaluollogo.jpeg they are both not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail blocking small embedded inline images in email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946783/gmail-blocking-small-embedded-inline-images-in-email-template) && [Image in Laravel 5.6 markdown mail not visible in Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073462/image-in-laravel-5-6-markdown-mail-not-visible-in-gmail/52076424)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Rename your images to something else with png, jpg or gif extensions only.
- Don't use any kind of query string in your image url like ?t=34343
- your image must include png, jpg or gif as an extension.
- your image url must be mapped onto your image directly.
- If you need to use some proxy url for your protected images then your response must include the proper header like Content-Type: image/jpeg
- File extension and content-type header must match
  Status-code must be 200 instead of 403, 500 etc

[Credit here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29184629/5513864)

There's other good solutions on that thread too.

Comment: "your image url must be mapped onto your image directly."

What does this mean?

Comment: With svg extension i have problem. Change to png fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You should not insert `SVG` images in the mail template. Please try with PNG, JPG..etc.

Also, check whether the image has public access is given or not.