# HTML conditional for Microsoft Outlook 2019

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am trying to build the html code designed for newsletter campaign. What I need is to find a solution for if statement, that outputs code for Microsoft Outlook 2019.

Working for Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019:

```
<!--[if mso 16]>
<span style="color:red">mso 16</span>
<![endif]-->
```

Not working at all:

```
<!--[if gt mso 16]>
<span style="color:red">gt mso 16</span>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso 19]>
<span style="color:red">mso 19</span>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if mso 365]>
<span style="color:red">mso 365</span>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any HTML conditional that allows to distinguish Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it appears Outlook 2019 uses the same conditional as Outlook 2016, as you have found (from testing in Litmus).

Additionally, Outlook doesn't support feature sniffing such as [@supports](https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/the-trap-of-using-supports-in-emails-495085641e87?gi=c55cb30724bf) (or the limited @media, except apparently on the Mac version).

The only way forward for differentiating them is that [Outlook 2019 apparently supports SVGs now](https://litmus.com/blog/microsoft-outlook-2019-heres-whats-new). I haven't been able to get this to work on my tests, but [SVG support across the board is pretty poor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981760/is-there-a-trick-to-display-svg-images-in-gmail) so I'm not sure it's any use anyway.