# Image not showing in Gmail / Yahoo mail

Tags: html, gmail

I have sent email using my html template.But when i send this email to Gmail / Yahoo  then image not showing When i check inspect email body elements, infront of image some other tags are added.

I have added jpg / png images.result is same

### My Html template

```
  <table>
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                    <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/DqF.svg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;" />
              </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

### Inspected Gmail Body

```
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/qX7T2O0am5PVOmfbHSLTZLdjuN0J3o0kiJi1YLNNf3vBGQe9j0YtQrA9aw4wyZWcbg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://svgshare.com/i/DqF.svg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px" class="CToWUd">
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=does+gmail+proxy+svg

Answer (score 2):

`svg` files are not supported by all email clients, Gmail is one of them. Yahoo I don't know. You should convert the svg file to png of jpg with any of the following tools:

https://www.google.com/search?q=svg+to+png+converter+online

Answer (score 0):

Gmail and Yahoo don't support svg as far as I know.
You can look at this question from a few years ago that might help:
[Is there a trick to display svg images in gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981760/is-there-a-trick-to-display-svg-images-in-gmail)

Comment: I have add png file.. result is same :(

Comment: @TechGuy https://help.campaignmonitor.com/why-recipients-may-not-see-images-in-emails Your email client is likely blocking images.