# Gmail not displaying images, its altering the src attribute

Tags: html, email, auto-responder

I have an autoresponder html message which I am sending to users' email addresses when they complete my form. in the message, I have html code to display my logo, however, the logo is not being displayed because my src attribute is getting changed.How can I fix this? this is the original src attribute:
**"https://storage.googleapis.com/emotion-studios-cloud/edupass/logo-blue.svg"**

and this is the src attribute being shown when I inspect the logo element in the email: **"https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/I5QkuAju6V1rX06BJFT3rOhlfQ6VN_09CcNDKuNvOjArUjLOvp4Ss5BgW8vDAI0OpThYFm5nV43E9XdDKbR1_RwY6KhHymEdEMsO1QYCYuBjQPn84_BBh1IApgZo=s0-d-e1-ft#[https://storage.googleapis.com/emotion-studios-cloud/edupass/logo-blue.svg"](https://storage.googleapis.com/emotion-studios-cloud/edupass/logo-blue.svg%22)**

Comment: Is the image available at the second location?

Comment: @Andy - not its not. that url gives a 404 error.

Comment: I believe you have a answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815613/svg-images-blocked-by-gmail-proxy/21064771#21064771
Please try with a PNG image to see if that’s still the issue.